# Using a method as a parameter for another method *Java Processing*

Tags: javascript, java, lambda, processing, method-reference

Hello I am working on a method which would apply a function (MATHEMATICAL such as f(x) = 3x + 2) to each element in an array. I plan on having this function being dynamic and having the ability to be changed depending on the example without changing the code (switching between different formulas). I want to store each of these MATHEMATICAL functions (formulas) in separate methods which would be called from one main method - mapFunc. mapFunc would have two parameters: the array which is being ran through the formula, and the method containing the chosen mathematical function. This is so that when calling the mapFunc method in my main loop, I would be able to write mapFunc(myArray, myFormula()). myFormula is a method. In java 8.0 I would be able to use a lambda expression and other method references to use myFormula() as a argument in mapFunc().However since I am using the software Processing which supports only Java7.0 fully, I am unable to use lambda expressions and other features included in Java8.0.
I want to have a method like this:

```
void mapFunction(float[][] data, myFormula()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = myFormula(data[i][j]));
        }
    }
 }
```

In javascript I would be able to write:

```
map(func) {
// Apply a function to every element of matrix
for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
    let val = this.data[i][j];
    this.data[i][j] = func(val);
  }
}
```

}

and then call it with myMatrix.map(double());

Helpful Links:
https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx - doesn't seem to work.

Comment: seams you need to read about the syntax of lambda expressions before trying to use, what you trying to do is tottally possible but your syntax is wrong. "Pass a method as parameter" doesn't mean write the name of the method to another method call. check: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-these-4-things-and-working-with-lambda-expressions-b0ab36e0fffc .In my opnion lambda is really needed in most of cases and many times makes your code more difficult to understand

Comment: @RafaelLima lambda is not supported in Processing and I am asking for alternatives

Comment: so why did you come with something way over complicated to a simple problem? create an interface `Formula` with one method `calc` and make as many implementations as you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Java had lambdas, the way to do this was to use anonymous instances of an interface like `Runnable`. Something like this:

```
void doTheThing(Runnable r){
  r.run();
}

doTheThing(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    yourFunctionHere();
  }
});
```

Or if your function takes a parameter, you can define your own interface like this:

```
interface ValueChanger{
  public float changeValue(float value);
}
```

Then you could create a function that takes a `ValueChanger` instance, like this:

```
void mapFunction(float[] data, ValueChanger valueChanger){
  data[0] = valueChanger.changeValue(data[0]);
}
```

And you could call your function by passing in an anonymous instance:

```
mapFunction(myArray, new ValueChanger(){
  public float changeValue(float value){
    return value * 2;
  }
});
```

Comment: So would you pass a 'Runnable' as the function which would be run?

Comment: @MatveyRyabov Yes, exactly.

Comment: I am still unsure on how to implement this into my code; I think I understand the first block of code but not the second.

Comment: @MatveyRyabov the second block of code creates an anonymous instance of `Runnable` and specifies a `run()` function. It then passes that instance into the `doTheThing()` function.

Comment: here is my attempt at implementing it into my code. However I seem to be getting syntax errors with no specific reason ("Error on double"). Do I need any special libraries or class modifications? https://codeshare.io/5Dn90W

Comment: @MatveyRyabov That link doesn't work for me, please edit your original post with your updated code.

Comment: @RafaelLima Please be more specific. What are these "dozens of misconcepts" you're talking about?

Comment: @MatveyRyabov You're trying to access `value` without `value` actually being in scope. You probably want to pass it as a parameter. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I tried to clarify my question. Hopefully it helps to explain to me your solution to my problem as I still do not understand it.

Comment: @MatveyRyabov I understand what you're trying to do. You're probably going to need to do some reading to understand anonymous instances in Java. I recommend reading [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) and googling "java anonymous instances" for a ton of results. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> However I am working in Processing and in this version I am unable to
>   use these strategies (syntax errors). Maybe I just don't understand
>   how these method references work

I don't see why what you try to do is not possible with lambda.
If you can use a Java 8 compiler you could write a method that accepts a `DoubleUnaryOperator` parameter that will be the function that you need to map a float to another float such as :

```
static void mapFunction(float[][] data, DoubleUnaryOperator function) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            data[i][j] = (float) function.applyAsDouble(data[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

For example this example sets the elements of the array with their squares :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float[][] data = new float[][] {{0F,1F}, {2F,3F}};
    mapFunction(data, a->a*a);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));

}
```

Output :

> [[0.0, 1.0], [4.0, 9.0]]

If you cannot note use Java 8 or + version or any third party library, you could introduce your own interface to map a float to a float and use a anonymous class instead of the lambda such as :

```
public interface FloatUnaryOperator  {
    float applyAsFloat(float operand);
}

static void mapFunction(float[][] data, FloatUnaryOperator function) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            data[i][j] = function.applyAsFloat(data[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    float[][] data = new float[][] {{0F,1F}, {2F,3F}};
    mapFunction(data, new FloatUnaryOperator() {

        @Override
        public float applyAsFloat(float operand) {
            return operand*operand;
        }
    });
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));
}
```

Comment: It gives an error that Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 and above. This is why I was confused by the second forum link which I provided because it sent mixed messages on whether lambda expressions are supported or not by Processing. As well I am getting an error that DoubleUnaryOperator does exist (class). I am wondering am I missing a library for that?

Comment: "It gives an error that Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 and above." It probably means that your IDE or your build tool (Maven, Gradle) is not configured to use Java  8. If you don't have company restrictions, you could use the Java version that you need. Just make sure that you downloaded, extracted it and configured to project to use it and it should be fine.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't clarify: Processing is a IDE with its own modified version of java which runs on Java 8.0 but for some reason doesn't support lambda  https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/24246/we-have-java-8-but-do-we-have-lambda. Actually it seems that it fully supports only up to java 7.

Comment: I am still unsure how to implement this into my code because I see lots of things which confuse me. I'm not sure if you understand what I mean by map so I will try to explain it differently. Sorry I didn't explain better before. I have an array of values. I am planning to take each element of the array and run it through a function such as f(x) = 3x + 2. I want to change this 'function' while I am running different examples so that when I call it it would look something like this. mapFunction(myArray, functionDouble()); Hopefully this clarifies some possible misconceptions.

Comment: About the Processing IDE, it seems even that the java 7 features be not supported by the IDE. : "We don't yet support any of the Java 7 and Java 8 language features." https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Supported-Platforms#java-versions.About your question, I saw your comment in the other answer. I think that it should be clear now. If it is not case, don't hesitate, I would explain :)